# org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for token submission

Tags: gemfire

Can someone look at this and provide your inputs what could be the issue?

```
Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.geode.internal.security.shiro.GeodeAuthenticationToken - null, rememberMe=false].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.geode.internal.security.shiro.GeodeAuthenticationToken - null, rememberMe=false].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
                at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:214)
                at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
                at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
                at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.security.IntegratedSecurityService.login(IntegratedSecurityService.java:139)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.HandShake.verifyCredentials(HandShake.java:1684)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.setCredentials(ServerConnection.java:1032)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.PutUserCredentials.cmdExecute(PutUserCredentials.java:50)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.execute(BaseCommand.java:165)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doNormalMsg(ServerConnection.java:780)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doOneMessage(ServerConnection.java:911)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:1166)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl$1$1.run(AcceptorImpl.java:523)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.geode.security.AuthenticationFailedException: ExampleSecurityManager: wrong username/password
                at org.apache.geode.examples.security.ExampleSecurityManager.authenticate(ExampleSecurityManager.java:145)
                at org.apache.geode.internal.security.shiro.CustomAuthRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(CustomAuthRealm.java:66)
                at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
                at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
                at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
                at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
                ... 15 more
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context as to what you're doing when this happens?

Comment: The cause says: `ExampleSecurityManager: wrong username/password`. Have you verified that you are providing the appropriate password? Also, if you are connecting from the client have you configured AuthInitializer?